How to ensure XSL-FO table (node A) continues at the top of the next page when node B spans multiple pages?
I'm using XSL-FO to generate a PDF where node A, represented by <fo:table/>, typically completes within a single page. Meanwhile, node B often spans multiple pages. When node B extends to the next page, I need node A to be duplicated and start afresh at the top of the subsequent page.
How can I achieve this behavior in XSL-FO/XSL-T? I am using Antenna House Formatter.
Here is the mock-up:


The two tables are exactly the same, I just manually change the contents here to indicate the table repeats at the 2nd page when its parent node spans multiple pages

I think that I know what you mean, but can you provide a graphic mock-up?

@TonyGraham Hi I added the mock-up to the description, thank you for the help!

Make an fo:table with your table as the fo:table-row in the fo:table-header, and put your steps in a single fo:table-cell in the single fo:table-row in the fo:table-body.
The table-omit-header-at-break property controls whether the header is repeated when the table breaks across a page.
